# WSO2 DAS 3.1.0 Select result fields with REST Search API

Tags: rest, solr, wso2-das

I've been trying WSO2DAS server and I'm looking for a way to limit the result fields from search queries. I'm using some fields to store potentially large content and I don't want to always have those in the results. The underlying SOLR seems to be able to support this using fl query parameter (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters) but I'm not able to specify those using the DAS REST API. I found some indications to put DAS on external SOLR implementation but it seems to be limited to the registry not the analytics events tables. Is there a way to select or limit output results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the required columns in the POST request payload body or as a request query parameter if it is a GET request. Unfortunately, this parameter was missing from the Docs. We have updated the REST API docs with the necessary changes. You can find updated documentation below

1. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+Records+Based+on+a+Time+Range+via+REST+API
2. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+All+Records+Matching+the+Given+Search+Query+via+REST+API
3. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+Specific+Records+through+a+Drill+Down+Search+via+REST+API
4. https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Retrieving+Records+Matching+the+Given+Primary+Key+Combination+via+REST+API

Comment: hi Gimantha, thank you for your answer, this is just what I was looking for,